# Find the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}\cos\left(\frac {k\pi}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}\cos\left(\frac {k\pi}{n}\right)$$
Where $[\frac {n}{2}]$ denotes Largest Integer not exceeding $\frac{n}{2}$.

I thought much about this problem but couldn't found any way to handle this,So I need your help to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are looking at almost the limit pf a Riemann sum.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but note that if the limit exists, it is independent of the manner in which $n\to\infty$; so you may assume that $n$ is even, and can rewrite it as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n\cos\left(\frac {k\pi}{2n}\right)$$

Comment: @MPW  Thanx for quick response. now can we handle this by integration?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 it is same. I searched but not found this. Thanxx

Comment: @@Chiranjeev) You are well come ..!!

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(x)$ is a concave function on the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, hence by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality):

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\left(O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\,dx\right)$$
so the wanted limit is just $\large\color{red}{2}$.

Comment: Sir Thanx for answer. As it is found as duplicate, can I delete my question?

Comment: @Chiranjeev: The question is yours, sure you can.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio if we want to solve this like $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \cos(x \pi) dx$, i got upper limit by multiplying $\lfloor  \frac{n}{2} \rfloor \times \frac{1}{n}$ as n goes to infinity it we get  1/2, Just curious can we use this method? and the answer will be $\frac{1}{\pi}$